# How to define string-right in scheme?

Tags: scheme, procedure

i need to define 'string-right' 
the procedure

```
(define string-right
  (lambda (x)
    (substring x (quotient (string-length x) 2) (string-length x))))
```

doesnt work on odd string lengths
but the prcoedure

```
(define string-right
    (lambda (x)
      (substring x (+ (quotient (string-length x) 2) 1)(string-length x))))
```

doesnt work on even string lengths. please help. frustrated.

Comment: What would you expect to be returned for: `(string-right "foo bar baz")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you meant you want the right half of a string without it's middle:
in quotient (the first option), replace:

```
(string-length x)
```

with:

```
(+ 1 (string-length x))
```

if length of the string is even, then 
floor((length + 1) / 2) = length / 2

otherwise
floor((length + 1) / 2) = (length + 1) / 2

the `+ 1` part would exclude the middle element

the full solution:

```
(define string-right
  (lambda (x)
    (substring x (quotient (+ 1 (string-length x)) 2) (string-length x))))
```

Comment: the REPL returned an error on both, using floor and ceiling. any other ideas?

Comment: the `floor` part of my answer was just an explanation, not part of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

```
(define string-right
  (lambda (x)
    (substring x (floor (/ (string-length x) 2)))))
```

The above procedure will include the character in the middle if the string length's is odd. If you don't want that, replace `floor` with `ceiling` and the middle char won't be present in the returned string.

Some examples using `floor`:

```
(string-right "")      ; => ""
(string-right "a")     ; => "a"
(string-right "ab")    ; => "b"
(string-right "abc")   ; => "bc"
(string-right "abcd")  ; => "cd"
(string-right "abcde") ; => "cde"
```

Some examples using `ceiling`:

```
(string-right "")      ; => ""
(string-right "a")     ; => ""
(string-right "ab")    ; => "b"
(string-right "abc")   ; => "c"
(string-right "abcd")  ; => "cd"
(string-right "abcde") ; => "de"
```